# Predict customer behaviour with Transformer(attention is all you need)

Tags: transformer, sequence-to-sequence, attention-mechanism

Please advice, am I thinking correctly: is it possible to represent customer behavior data from an online store as a sequence data? Because it is describing interactions of the customer with the shop through time.

So in this case N would be the number of users (or number of user sessions), T / time window I could set myself and D I could set also myself taking only event type (purchase, view, etc.) or something else like price, brand etc.(please see screenshot below)
[image]

Please share your opinion
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, it is a good idea and has been attempted before.
Have a look at Alibaba's paper which uses transformers:
https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/08/order-matters-alibabas-transformer-based-recommender-system.html

https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.06874

There are also various other papers that use other types of seq2seq for recommender systems.

Comment: thank you for links!

Comment: in this case, if I have have only e.g. 16 features, than my model dimension (d_model) will be 16...is it even possible? In the attention paper they have 512...